# Phonegap, BackboneJS, UnderscoreJS, RequireJS issues with templates

Tags: android, cordova, backbone.js, requirejs, underscore.js

I am writing an Android app with Phonegap, BackboneJS, UnderscoreJS, RequireJS.

I have a collection of 4 models which is passed to a template like:

```
    initialize: function(){
        var self = this;
        this.collection = new RestaurantsCollection();
        this.collection.fetch();
        this.collection.on("add reset", this.render, this);
      },
render:function () {
    this.$el.html(_.template(HomeViewTemplate, {collection: this.collection}));
    return this;
},
```

And in the template I have:

```
<%=collection.length%> //outputs 4
<% collection.each(function(model){ %>
<h1>FOO</h1><br /> //doesnt work at all
<% }); %>
```

In Chrome I get the expected output (above), but when I run it in the AND emulator I get

```
<%=collection.length%> //outputs 0
```

Any suggestions appreciated. I just need some direction as to what the issue might be.

Comment: Do you call render right after fetch?

Comment: @jakee Yes, I do. I get the page as expected, just the collection is empty.

Comment: What happens if you call `render` in the `fetch` success handler instead?

Comment: And its just like `collection.fetch(); this.render();`?

Comment: @muistooshort Then <%=collection.length%> //outputs 0 in Chrome and the emulator

Comment: @jakee I have added some more view code so you can see how exactly I am fetching the collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly enough, the URL in the collection was /my-url and changing it to my-url solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I actually found a solution to my answer, here it is:

**WRONG:**

```
<%=collection.length%> //outputs 4
<% collection.each(function(model){ %>
<h1>FOO</h1><br /> //doesnt work at all
<% }); %>
```

**CORRECT**

```
<%=collection.length%> //outputs 4
<% _.each(colleciton.models, function(model){ %>
<%console.log(model.get('id'))%>
<% }); %>
```